# Are URLs to doxygen pages permanent

Tags: doxygen

hey everyone, we just added a nightly action to process the entire source tree with doxygen and place the output onto development webserver.

We also already have a sharepoint structure which holds design documents for various modules/projects.  Currently, the level at which we are keeping this documentation is relatively high.  We discuss structures of modules and talk about the major classes, but never go down to the individual method level.  I wanted to bridge that gap by having hyperlinks in the SDS word documents that would point to doxygen output.

I noticed the links look like this:

```
http://example.com/docs/ProjectName/d4/d98/class_c_reader.html
http://example.com/docs/ProjectName/d4/d16/class_c_stream.html
```

The part that sketches me out a bit is "d4", "d98" and "d16" strings in the path.  If I copy these links and create the hyperlinks, does anyone know if these URLs are guaranteed be preserved in the future.  As I said, entire doxygen output gets regenerated nightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably these links will not stay permanent.
Furthermore, Doxygen has a XML representation of the generated documentation but even this interface resp. the corresponding DSD has been changed with new releases of doxygen. This is quite frustrating, as we had used the XML representation for a similar application with the assumption that the structures would be kept identical with every new release.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the `d4/d98` subdirectories by disabling [CREATE_SUBDIRS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_create_subdirs) in the doxygen configuration.

Whether the name of the HTML files will stay the same I do not know for sure but from what I have seen when using doxygen it seems so. If you want to know for sure you can always look at the doxygen source.