# How to hyperlink to deep Doxygen content?

Tags: doxygen, permalinks

As implied by [Are URLs to doxygen pages permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705703), URL in doxygen are **not** permanent.

So, how do you hyperlink deep content (ex: a specific function) in doxygen from an external site/doc ?

(For now, hinting the user on using the search box from the home seems an adequate workaround)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links *are* based on the function signature, so they persistent indeed (under the condition that `SHORT_NAMES` is set to `NO`, which is the default).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Howto-get-HTML-links-to-functions-so-external-documents-links-o-function-documentation--td20025814.html):

> Doxygen does generate persistent links already (unless `SHORT_NAMES` is set to `YES`).

This is from the creator of doxygen (who might want to chip in here with his own, more definitive answer than mine). So it seems that you can safely assume that your URLs should not change, unless you change the names of your classes/functions of course.

Comment: +1. Thx ! Oh, and i'm sorry, but I accepted the answer from @doxygen, for obvious reasons.